# Rails 4 - form with namespace model name spliting route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 4 app with an admin namespace and a model called Gametime

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :gametimes
end
```

the model is game_time.rb

```
class GameTime < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The index and show action work fine. I am having a problem with the new action.

gametimes_controller.rb

```
def new
  @gametime = GameTime.new
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% form_for [:admin, @gametime ] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error

```
 NoMethodError at /admin/gametimes/new 
 undefined method `admin_game_times_path' for #<#<Class:0xae0d74c>:0xae0c2c0

 Request parameters 
 {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"admin/gametimes"}
```

The routes show this

```
  new_admin_gametime GET    /admin/gametimes/new(.:format)       admin/gametimes#new
```

I don't see why it putting the path as "game_time" rather than "gametime" ?

Comment: Because your model is `GameTime` not `Gametime`, that's why you get space between the two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is named `GameTime` with capital "G" and "T". `form_for` will assume the route for that to be `game_time`.

If you want the default route to be `gametime`, the model should be named `Gametime` - ie with only the "G" being capitalized.

Internally `form_for` uses `ActiveModel::Name#param_key` to figure out that part of the URL, which illustrates the behaviour you're seeing:

```
GameTime.model_name.param_key # => "game_time"
Gametime.model_name.param_key # => "gametime"
```

Note how the file with your model is also named `game_time.rb`, so there is some consistency there.